# Creating concatenation predicate in prolog that works with only one input instantiation

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to create a predicate in Prolog that concatenates two lists and works in any case of these:

```
concat(X,Y,[1,2,3,4]) 
concat(X,[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
concat([1,2,3],X,[1,2,3,4])
```

The best I could make so far was this:

```
concat([],[],[]).
concat([],X,X).
concat(X,[],X).
concat([X|Y],[A|B],[X|Z]) :- add(Y,[A],K) , add(K,B,Z) .
```

with the following results:

works correctly:

```
concat([1,2,3],X,[1,2,3,4])
```

gives correct answer, then enters infinite loop:

```
concat(X,[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
```

gives some results (edit: all results, I believe), then enters infinite loop:

```
concat(X,Y,[1,2,3,4])
```

results given:

```
?- concat(X,Y,[1,2,3,4]).
X = [],
Y = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
X = [1,2,3,4],
Y = [] ? ;
X = [1],
Y = [2,3,4] ? ;
X = [1,2],
Y = [3,4] ? ;
X = [1,2,3],
Y = [4] ? ;
```

I'm trying to make this predicate to learn more about prolog.

Comment: The usual `append/3` definition will do.

Comment: If you google "prolog concat" or "prolog append" you'll find a few implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, you're just redefining `append/3`. However, as a learning experience you should notice that you can do this in a simpler and more Prolog-y way:

```
concat([],X,X).
concat([X|Y],A,[X|Z]) :- 
     concat(Y,A,Z).
```

As you see, the definitions for empty second list are needless because in the first definition Prolog copies (or more exactly, *unifies*) second list to the third (or vice versa) even if it is an empty one. You need to handle an empty list only in the first list to stop the recursion. Besides, using pattern matching you don't need extra predicates to move the head items from a list to another.